# How to initialize wchar_t pointer variable in c++?

Tags: c++, mfc

I like to know how to initialize and how to copy the contents of one wchar_t* variable into another wchar_t* variable.

```
    wchar_t *lfFace = new wchar_t;
    dc.GetTextFaceW(LF_FACESIZE,lfFace);
```

This sample will throw runtime error.Please correct these.

Thnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CStringW` instead. Like this:

```
CStringW faceName;
dc.GetTextFaceW(faceName);
```

Comment: But GetTextFaceW is an MFC function, he can't change its signature.

Comment: It has an overload for `CString`, which is definitely better.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that. This will only work if the application is compiled as unicode though.

Comment: You're not compiling as Unicode? Why not? Also you can use `CStringW` for a `wchar_t` version of `CString`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsbff794%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you'll want something like this:

```
wchar_t *lfFace = new wchar_t[LF_FACESIZE];
dc.GetTextFaceW(LF_FACESIZE, lfFace);
// do stuff with lfFace
delete [] lfFace;
```

Comment: You linked to the Windows API function, OP is using the MFC member function which takes two parameters.

Comment: @interjay - Right you are.  Updated with that version to be useful in addition to your answer.